# Flutter Remove selected element from list

Tags: flutter, list, dart

I try to remove the element from list I am clicking on. I think I have to specify the parameters in the Todos class, but dont know what I have to add, maybe with Id's and increment the Id but how would i catch the current ID. Here is a Snipped from the debugger and a the Todo class code

[image: herePic]

Here is TODO class:

```
class Todo {
  Todo({required this.name, required this.checked});

  final String name;
  bool checked;

  static Todo fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return Todo(name: json['name'], checked: json['checked']);
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    return {
      'name': name,
      'checked': checked,
    };
  }
}

class TodoItem extends StatelessWidget {
  TodoItem({
    required this.todo,
    required this.onTap,
    required this.onDelete,
  }) : super(key: ObjectKey(todo));

  final Todo todo;
  final Function onTap;
  final Function onDelete;

  TextStyle? _getTextStyle(bool checked) {
    if (!checked) return null;

    return const TextStyle(
      color: Colors.black54,
      decoration: TextDecoration.lineThrough,
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListTile(
      onTap: () {
        onTap(todo);
      },
      leading: CircleAvatar(
        child: Text(todo.name[0]),
      ),
      title: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
        children: [
          Text(todo.name, style: _getTextStyle(todo.checked)),
          IconButton(
              onPressed: () {
                print(todo.name);
                onDelete();
              },
              icon: Icon(Icons.delete))
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: can you please add the code where you're using `TodoItem` widget?

Comment: How are you building those TodoItem's? Are you using a ListView.builder?

Comment: Sure sorry here :  `Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return  Scaffold(
      body: ListView(
        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 8.0),
        children: _todos.map((Todo todo) {
          return TodoItem(
            todo: todo,
            onTap: _handleTodoChange, onDelete: (){
            setState(() {
            });

          }
          );
        }).toList(),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
          onPressed: () => _displayDialog(),
          tooltip: 'Add Item',
          child: const Icon(Icons.add)),
    );
  }`

Answer (score 0):

You could set the `onDelete` parameter to call `_deleteTodoItem` using Contructor like this:

```dart
ListView(
  // other params ...
  children: _todos
      .map(
        (todo) => TodoItem(
          onDelete: () async {
            await _deleteTodoItem(todo.name);
          },
          // other params
          onTap: () {}, // set it to whatever,
          todo: todo,
        ),
      )
      .toList(),
  // other params ...
);
```

Comment: I added the Listview Builder

Comment: Cool... the main thing is `onDelete` in the answer.

Comment: I m not able to convert my normal Listview to a ListView builder because of this Scaffold above D:

Comment: Added ListView in my answer. I repeat that the main thing is onDelete in the answer.

Comment: Ah yes i understand, but where do i get the index? yet its Undefined name 'index'.

Comment: My bad... oops. Changed it :D

Comment: And what about the Function _deleteTodoItem? I still dont know how do I find the   _todos.removeWhere [...]

Answer (score 0):

If you now the index of you list, you can do:

```
_todos.removeAt(index);
```

So... you can modify your code to find the index using a listviewbuilder:

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView.builder(
      physics: ScrollPhysics(),
      scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
      itemCount: _todos.length,
      itemBuilder: (BuildContext ctx, index) {
      return ListTile(
      onTap: () {
        onTap(todo);
      },
      leading: CircleAvatar(
        child: Text(todo.name[0]),
      ),
      title: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
        children: [
          Text(todo.name, style: _getTextStyle(todo.checked)),
          IconButton(
              onPressed: () {
                print('${todo.name} index: $index');
                onDelete(index);
              },
              icon: Icon(Icons.delete))
        ],
      ),
     ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: Ye I see your plan but still have problems to convert stuff and I cant modify my class like that because I have to add the todos to a JSON in another class

Comment: Just put a listViewBuilder and pass the Index for your delete function. Don't work for you ?

Comment: Yet my code is:  `Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: ListView(
        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 8.0),
        children: _todos.map((Todo todo) {
          return (TodoItem(
            onDelete: () async {
              await _deleteTodoItem(_todos[index].name);
            },
            // other params
            onTap: () {}, // set it to whatever,
            todo: _todos[index],
          ));
        }).toList(),
      ),`

Comment: I use a scaffold to show the listview. I am not so good in flutter so i have no idea how i use a scaffold in a listview builder